# SQL Server 2016 SE using high memory and crashes

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2016

we are using SQL Server 2016 SE on AWS EC2 (4 core 16 GB). over the period of time its memory usages increases and when it reaches 90 % then it stops working . We have to manually restart server then its fine and this cycle continues after every 7-8 days.

Comment: Have you set max memory?

Comment: no its default one. but why its crashing?

Comment: does the OS hang or just sql server? and what do you mean by 'stops working'? can you still connect/run a query?

Comment: SQL server hangs and my application cannot connect to SQL. I have to RDP SERVER and manually restart SQL Server process then it start working

Comment: I'd set max memory to see if that has an impact. there could possible be a big memory grant somewhere which is spilling to disk and causing an issue. Also look the the log in SSMS go Management > Sql Server Log and see if there are any interesting messages when it crashes.